# ansible create user: no default .bashrc created?

Tags: ansible

I am creating users with these tasks:

```
- name: ensure home directory
  sudo: yes
  file: path={{item.home}} state=directory
  with_items: users

- name: create user {{item.name}}
  sudo: yes
  user: name={{item.name}} home={{item.home}} shell=/bin/bash group={{item.group}} groups={{item.groups}} password={{item.password}} state=present
  with_items: users
```

but it seems that a ~/.bashrc per user is not created in their home directory.

Is there a way to create a default basic .bashrc file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Ansible 2.0, you can pass along a `skeleton` option:

> Optionally set a home skeleton directory. Requires createhome option!

This works for me:

```
- name: "Create deployment user"
  user:
    name: "foobar"
    groups: "sudo"
    append: yes
    skeleton: "/etc/skel"
    createhome: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a specific path for the home folders (different than the traditionnal /home/user1 folder): `/specific/path/home/user1`

Since I had an error that the path `/specific/path/home/user1` could not be created when I was creating the user1, I then created the home folders before creating the users.
However if the home folder already exists when a user is created, the default `.bashrc` is not copied.

Comment: This error occurs even if you do not specify a specific path, FWIW.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `append=yes` at the end of the user command 
user:

```
- name: Add users
  add_user:
    name: '{{item.name}}'
    home: '{{item.home}}'
    shell: /bin/bash
    group: '{{item.group}}'
    groups: '{{item.groups}}'
    password: '{{item.password}}'
    state: present
    append: yes 
with_items: users
```